# How to extend the methods of dll to a class with same name?

Tags: c#, dll

Suppose this situation:

Dll have as namespace `Users` and as class `User`.
 Now in my own program I've a different namespace as `Test` but I've the same class name of the dll `User`.

Usually for avoid this situation I using the alias, so:

```
using UserDLL = Users.User;

namespace Test
{
    class User : Tenant
    { 
        public void doSomething()
        {
            UserDLL.AddUser(); //call dll method
        }
    }
}
```

but there is a way to include dll method in the class directly? So I can call just `User.AddUser()`?

**UPDATE**

A possible solution is the inherit from the class of dll, but what happean if I already have a class inherit? For example `User` inherit `Tenant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either inherit from Users.User (recommended) or consider making extension methods for it instead of having a separate class.

Inheritance approach:

```
 namespace Test {
  public class User : Users.User
  {
         public void DoSomething(){}
  }
 }
```

...extension method:

```
 public static class UserExtensions{
       public static void DoSomething(this Users.User user)
        {
             var val = user.AddUser();
        }
 }


 //then you can do something like this:
 var u = new Users.User();
 u.DoSomething();
```

Comment: Uhm well, but if I have already a inherit class? Example updated.

Comment: In that case, go with an extension method as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Uhm should I create another class? Why you've called `UserExtension`?

Comment: Yes. Extension methods need to be placed in a static class (so they need to be outside the Tenant.User class). They can then add methods to classes you don't inherit from as shown in my latest tweaked example.